# Inverting Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, inversion

Here as an example. Participants rank their favorite colors between green, blue and red.
id represent participants. Each participant ranked three colors from 1-3(best=1, second favorite=2, least favorite=3). Imagine the data looks like this:

```
         id1      id2     id3
 rank1   red     green    blue
 rank2   green   blue     red
 rank3   blue    red      green
```

I need to change the values so that it looks like this:

```
        id1   id2    id3
 green   2      1     3
 blue    3      2     1
 red     1      3     2
```

Essentially, I want to create a row with the color and record its ranking. My actual dataframe is 25 columns x 100 rows. I am doing this because data entry is easier in version 1.

What is the easist way to change the data?

Comment: Student, do either of the answers adequately address your question? If so, please remember to "accept" one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sapply` a `match` to each column of your dataframe:

```
# example data
df <- data.frame(
    id1 = c("red", "green", "blue"),
    id2 = c("green", "blue", "red"),
    id3 = c("blue", "red", "green"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# create ranking dataframe
sapply(df, match, x=c("green", "blue", "red"))
```

Result:

```
  id1 id2 id3 
1   2   1   3 
2   3   2   1 
3   1   3   2
```

Comment: Cool approach, I would add the following: you can go directly `sapply` instead of `lapply` and avoid `as.data.frame`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tidyr::spread` and `::gather` for this:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
         id1      id2     id3
 rank1   red     green    blue
 rank2   green   blue     red
 rank3   blue    red      green')

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(id, color, -rowname) %>%
  spread(id, rowname) %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames(var="color")
#         id1   id2   id3
# blue  rank3 rank2 rank1
# green rank2 rank1 rank3
# red   rank1 rank3 rank2
```

(The `column_to_rownames` was solely to meet your spec'd output, not that I recommend using row names.)

You can insert a command to remove the `rank` text from the ranks, if desired:

```
dat %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(rowname = gsub("\\D", "", rowname)) %>%
  gather(id, color, -rowname) %>%
  spread(id, rowname) %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames(var="color")
#       id1 id2 id3
# blue    3   2   1
# green   2   1   3
# red     1   3   2
```

or even `mutate(rowname = as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", rowname)))` if you need them to be integers.

Comment: An alternative to `gsub`, since you're already in the tidyverse, is to extract digits with `stringr::str_extract(rowname, "\\d+)`. I often have an easier time keeping track of what I want to extract than what I want to substitute with a blank.

Comment: Good point ... though I try to reduce external package loading unless it cannot be done (easily) in base R. In this case, I did not load `tidyverse` so I don't assume it's installed. I don't install the whole meta-package, just the ones I need. Preference, certainly, and more these days it seems to be rather religious: `library(tidyverse)` is a bit harsh in my opinion, especially with namespace conflicts (in general in R) they way they are.